# Find and Replace with command line

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

my `log.txt` file includes

```
...
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
...
```

how can I replace

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
```

with

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 0.0.0.0/0
```

from the command Line? In other words, I want to add `0.0.0.0/0` to the end of that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add the specified text to a line in the file - *if that line is the only one that starts with `mynetworks`*, you can do this:

```
sed --in-place '/^mynetworks/s_.*_& 0.0.0.0/0_' /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 3):

**Using sed**

```
sed -i 's+^mynetworks.*+& 0.0.0.0/0+' log.txt
```

**Using awk**

```
awk '/^mynetworks/ {$0=$0" 0.0.0.0/0"} 1' log.txt
```

or

```
awk '{if ($1 ~ /^mynetworks/) print $0, "0.0.0.0/0"; else print $0}' log.txt
```

**Using bash**

```
while read -r line ; do
    [[ $line == mynetworks* ]] && line+=" 0.0.0.0/0"
    echo "$line"
done < log.txt
```

Comment: That will add `0.0.0.0/0` to _every_ line in the file.

Comment: `log.txt` include many lines  ,  i want `awk` add end of this line `mynetworks =`

Comment: @MehranGoudarzi see my updates

Comment: @DopeGhoti yeah, actually I misunderstood requirements. thanks

Comment: There's no point in using `g` when you're anchoring the regex to the beginning of the line (`^`). In any case, the `g` will make `sed` replace every occurrence in each line, not "globally in the file", but "globally on the line". It is only useful if you expect more than one match per line, not more than one per file (that's what sed does anyway).

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use Perl. sed or awk is fine in this case, but sometimes the flexibility is Perl is useful.

```
perl -pi -e 's/^(mynetworks.*)/$1 0.0.0.0\/0/' /path/to/file
```

or if this is in a pipe chain

```
cat file | perl -pe 's/^(mynetworks.*)/$1 0.0.0.0\/0/'
```